# Кастомная аутентификация на Laravel 6 через стороннюю api

Tags: laravel, api, аутентификация

Не могу понять как сделать собственную аутентификацию через стороннюю api в laravel 6.

У api есть метод login, при удачной проверки логина и пароля возвращается токен, который мне нужно сохранить в куки и использовать в дальнейших запросах к api, база данных в моем прректе не используется, вся работа идет через api. Проверка токена на валидность идет также через api.
Если пользователь имеет валидный токен, то соответственно он считается авторизованным. Выход также выполняется через api, токен удаляется.

Читал что нужно делать свой провайдер для пользователей и laravel будет сравнивать с ним и генерировать как я понимаю свой токен, но мне нужно сохранять только тот токен, который идет из самого api.

Comment: Аутентификацию на основе токена хотите делать? Или к примеру как существует вход через Google на другие сайты?

Comment: Да, на основе токена, который возвращает api. Это api не гугла или других соцсетей.

Comment: А в чем именно сложность? Вы описали собственно, что нужно сделать. Весь функционал можно описать в middleware

Comment: @YauhenKib спасибо, сделал через middleware

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделал проверку токена через middleware, как посоветовал @YauhenKib.
https://webstool.ru/kak-sdelat-middleware-v-laravel-6.html